# Align TextView with the ImageView in another Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to align four imageview and textview, but there is three lines between imageviews. I need to align TextView1 with ImageView1, TextView2 with ImageView2, TextView3 with ImageView3, and TextView4 with ImageView4, but it's not getting aligned. This is my code. Please help me with how I can achieve this. I uploaded images for reference.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/constLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/paid"
            app:tint="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/paid"
            app:tint="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/paid"
            app:tint="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/paid"
            app:tint="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Text One" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text Two" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text Three" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text Four" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**This is my layout:**

[image]

**I need Layout like this:**

[image]

Comment: Seems like a RelativeLayout is a better match for your task.

Comment: Can you help with code?

Comment: Either that or a [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea how to do it with RelativeLayout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/left1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/right1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img1"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img1"
        >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/left2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img2"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/line1"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/right2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a very long text 1"
        android:layout_below="@id/img1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/left1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/right1"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a very long text 2"
        android:layout_below="@id/img2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/left2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/right2"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of creating complex layout is using `ConstraintLayout`

here sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">
    
    <!-- image view -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img3"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img4"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <!-- line between  -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img2"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img3"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img4"/>
    
    <!-- txt step -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Step 1 text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/img1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Step 2 text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/img2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/img2"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Step 3 text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/img3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/img3"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Step 4 text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/img4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/img4"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the result

[image]